# How to convert molecule structure to 3D PyTorch tensors for CNN?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I want to try convolutional neural networks for drugs classification. I use PyTorch for 3D CNN implementation. Is there a way to obtain 3D tensors from SMILES or SDF/PDB structures?

Comment: PDB is already a 3D representation, but SMILES is not.

Comment: This seems like a much better fit for [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the conversion of SMILES into 1D and 2D representations.  Is there any reason you specifically wish to use 3D tensors? I haven't seen 3D tensors in literature, but that isn't to say that it doesn't exist.

[torchdrug](https://torchdrug.ai/docs/installation.html) converts SMILES molecules graphs based on NetworkX. You can install it using:
*pip install torchdrug*
Be aware that it only works for python 3.6-3.9.

[pysmilesutils](https://github.com/MolecularAI/pysmilesutils) converts SMILES into a vector. You can install it using the following commands:
*python -m pip install git+https://github.com/MolecularAI/pysmilesutils.git*

[PyTorch Geometric](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html) converts SMILES into a matrix constructed of property vectors of each atom in the molecule.

Comment: Thank you! The three-dimensional structures that can be obtained from molecular docking provide useful information about the geometry of the molecule within the binding pocket. But PyTorch CNN cannot work with SDF or PDB files, it requires tensors. In the case of three-dimensional structures - three-dimensional tensors. [This link](https://youtu.be/IOxujXGYuB4) can give you more information about this approach -

Comment: I know a computational chemist who specialises in ML for drug-target interaction, I'll ask them about this and get back to you!